# How do I automatically backup a file to OneDrive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

I have an important file in c:\users\me\app\roaming\foo\, is there any way to mark it so that it automatically syncs to onedrive?

edit: Other solutions involve scheduled backups to the OneDrive directory. I would rather not use additional tools and would like to have the directory sync automatically (to take advantage of change detection and instantaneous sync). I ended up using mklink.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have installed one drive and logged it in using you MS account, you can create a symbolic link that makes the Target folders and files appear within the link. EG.

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

MKLINK /J C:\Users\me\documents\foo C:\Users\me\app\roaming\foo
```

Note: Ensure the chosen folder is synced to OneDrive and the folder foo within your link folder does not exist before the command.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be to save the file in your OneDrive directory. It should automatically sync changes as you save the file.

Comment: I don't have control over the location of the file. The application expects it in a certain local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since the directories are on the same partition I was able to use mklink to create symbolic link into the onedrive folder.